# std::vector content change when read inside the main()

Tags: c++, string, winapi, vector

I was writing this function to search a file inside the computer but i encountered a problem: When I read the files that have been found during the search(using the for cycle inside the main() ) the directory are broken.
With some debugging I saw that when pushed inside the file_found vector,they are intact,but when i read the vector in the main they're like overlapped and with a "*" at the end.How can i fix this?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <Windows.h>

    int SearchForFileW(WCHAR * fileName,LPWSTR dir,std::vector<LPWSTR>& file_found)
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATAW winFindDataFirst;

        HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFileW(dir,&winFindDataFirst);

        if (!wcscmp(winFindDataFirst.cFileName,fileName))
        {
            wchar_t tmp[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
            _snwprintf(tmp, wcslen(dir) - wcslen(L"*"), dir);
            wcscpy(dir, tmp);
            wcscat(dir, winFindDataFirst.cFileName);
            file_found.push_back(dir);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            if (FindNextFileW(hFile, &winFindDataFirst) == 0)
            {
                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                { 
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            if (!wcscmp(winFindDataFirst.cFileName, L".") ||
                !wcscmp(winFindDataFirst.cFileName, L".."))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(!wcscmp(winFindDataFirst.cFileName,fileName))
            {
                wchar_t tmp[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
                _snwprintf(tmp, wcslen(dir) - wcslen(L"*"), dir);
                wcscpy(dir, tmp);
                wcscat(dir, winFindDataFirst.cFileName);
                file_found.push_back(dir);
            }

            if ((winFindDataFirst.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {   
                wchar_t tmp[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
                _snwprintf(tmp, wcslen(dir) - wcslen(L"*"), dir);
                wcscpy(dir, tmp);
                wcscat(dir, winFindDataFirst.cFileName);
                wcscat(dir, L"\\*");
                SearchForFileW(fileName, dir,file_found);
                _snwprintf(tmp, wcslen(dir) - (wcslen(winFindDataFirst.cFileName) + wcslen(L"\\*")), dir);
                wcscpy(dir, tmp);
                wcscat(dir, L"*");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("File:-------%S\n\n", winFindDataFirst.cFileName);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

int main()
{
    std::vector<LPWSTR> file;
    WCHAR dirBuff[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    wcscpy(dirBuff,L"c:\\*");
    SearchForFileW(L"MyFile.txt", dirBuff,file);
    if (file.size() == 0)
    {
        printf("No file found");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++)
        {
            printf("File found at: %S\n", file.at(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep writing to `dir` and keep pushing back the same, so the *last* time you write to `dir` is what *all* elements of the vector point to. Just use `std::vector<std::wstring>` instead of all of the string copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::vector<LPWSTR>` is a **`std::vector<wchar_t*>`** (since `LPWSTR` is a typedef for `wchar_t*`).

Now, having a vector of **raw owning pointers** is very fragile. You can have a vector of raw *observing* pointers, and you must be sure that the strings pointed to are still allocated (kind of "live") when you refer them using those pointers.
And that is *not* your case.

The simplest thing to do is to just use C++ string classes like **`std::wstring`** instead of the raw `wchar_t*` pointers.
So, you can substitute your `vector<LPWSTR>` with a **`vector<wstring>`**. In this case, the lifetime of the strings will be *automatically* managed by the C++ compiler and the STL implementation: you can focus on the core of your algorithm, not on bug-prone string memory management implementation details.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer plus pushing inside file_found tmp and not dir and the algorithm work perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

`LPWSTR` is just sugar coating for `someKindOfChar*` Which means it is a pointer. Which means that `vector<LPWSTR>` is a vector of pointers. And every time, you use the same buffer to save your file name in (`dir`). So you every time copy your filename in this, and push its address to your vector.

To fix, either use a `std::vector<std::wstring>`.

Or do it the hard way: use `malloc(strlen(tmp)+1)` for every found file to allocate data for your string. Note however, that LPWSTR stands for, i believe *long pointer wide string*. This means that normal `strlen`might not work, since it could contain special non-ascii characters

Comment: No reason to use `malloc` here (and should use `new` in C++ instead of `malloc` but prefer smart pointers). `std::string` is incorrect since they need wide characters (`std::wstring`).

Comment: Thanks, i sort of forgot